# Adding video and flash functionality to the Ajax Control Toolkit HTMLEditor

Tags: flash, video, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, html-editor

Greetings, I'm looking for a way to extend the functionality of the HTMLEditor control that the Ajax Control Toolkit supplies for ASP.net. I would like to add video and flash functionality to the editor (buttons, allowed tags, etc).

To my knowledge, this is rather easy: plop in an embed tag with the correct parameters and it just works; I have videos running in the preview window of the editor.

Unfortunately, the  tag is stripped away when saving the HTML-code and updating it in the database.

Hence, I would like to ask if there is any way of adding this functionality apart from manually adding the changes in the source control repository of the Ajax Control Toolkit and recompiling it. If this is not possible, but you can offer some help concerning the implementation of this in the source code, it would also be much appreciated.

Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have switched to CKEditor and CKFinder; they offer built-in functionality to upload, browse and implement Flash-based videos. I've written a small plugin that builds up a link that interfaces with ShadowBox to get a "modal popup"-type functionality. Works wonderfully.

If you wish to get the source code to the plugin (and some general documentation as to how I configured it), don't hesitate to e-mail me.

Comment: Hi, how can I take this plugin?